# How to consume Google map web services API in my flutter APP

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dart, flutter, dart-pub

I am new in Flutter, and I have pretty good knowledge of using Google maps APIs for native Android Apps. However, in my flutter app, I need Google Places search Auto-complete. I came across a plugin called [google_maps_webservice](https://github.com/lejard-h/google_maps_webservice) where it consumes google maps APIs such as directions, places and geocoding using Google web services. My question is having low understanding and experiences in setting up web services for google maps API, how I can use the plugin in my flutter app? For example, if I had to use places API in android I would have enabled **Goole Places SDK** in cloud console and generate an API restricting for Android App. But for a flutter, both Android and iOS are going to use the same services from a web API call. what should I do? And right now I have no backend knowledge to set up a domain to use while creating the API from the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can import the google_maps_webservices package

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
```

and use it in your code:

```
final places = GoogleMapsPlaces('<Your-API-Key>');
final response = await places.autocomplete('<What-you-are-searching-for>');

if (response.isOkay) {
  for (Prediction prediction in response.predictions) {
    print(prediction.description);
   }
}
```

Some caveats:
 1. Ensure that you are using the Web API key
 2. Ensure to activate the Google Places SDK in Cloud Console.
 3. To avoid getting an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` `status` message, ensure that you are using a billing account.